# Which multiplayer weapons are available at each rarity level?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

This question is about multiplayer.

I'm not sure which packs I should get. I'm mostly getting Advanced packs so far, so I can get an occasional rare item but focus on ranking up ones I have while still getting enough consumables and boosters.

My main motivation for getting more expensive packs would be if there was a specific thing I wanted to unlock at a higher rarity level.

I can see which classes are available at each rarity level by looking at the character selection screen. I'd like a Human Kineticist, but I'm not going to throw all my credits at the most expensive packs just for the chance of unlocking that alone.

However, I don't think there's an in-game screen showing me all the weapons I might unlock and their rarity levels.

Which weapons are available at each rarity level?

Weapon stats would be nice, but I think they're all available in the single-player campaign, so I should have a decent idea of how each gun works already.

Comment: Weapon stats can be very different between single-player and multiplayer.  Many people consider multiplayer weapon stats to be incorrect today, and expect a tuning patch at minimum and a complete revamp at maximum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see the multiplayer gun collection in-game.  From the main multiplayer screen select "prestige", then "collection".  Use the subtle top tab menu to switch from characters to weapons.  Then use the filtering button until you get to the desired rarity.

[image: Ultra Rare Weapons collection]

Don't have time to look in game?  Got you covered:

Common

```
Assault Rifle: Avenger
Pistol: Charger, Predator
Shotgun: Katana
Sniper Rifle: Viper
```

Uncommon

```
Assault Rifle: Cyclone, Mattock, Zalkin
Pistol: Carnifex, Phalanx
Shotgun: Disciple, Ruzad
Sniper Rifle: Incisor, Raptor, Widow
```

Rare

```
Assault Rifle: Hesh, Falcon, Revenant, Sandstorm, Thokin, Halberd
Pistol: Equalizer, Scorpion, Sidewinder, Talon, Hornet
Shotgun: Scattershot, Sweeper
Sniper Rifle: Indra, Vanquisher, Isharay, Lanat
```

Ultra Rare

```
Assault Rifle: N7 Valkyrie, P.A.W., Soned
Pistol: N7 Eagle, N7 Hurricane, Rozerad, Ushior
Shotgun: Dhan, N7 Crusader, N7 Piranha
Sniper Rifle: Naladen, Black Widow, N7 Valiant
```

Many items have incorrect categories in the collection menu.  That's ME:A baby!
I've corrected for this to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Never even opened that menu before. Gonna have to open some more rares for the guns.